# Where is GetChildHtml('left') template file Or included template parts defined

Tags: magento-1.9, template

The `local.xml` and `page.xml` files in our theme do not specify any files for the sidebars' content, nor in the base theme which I assume this one inherits from. But there is content in both, not present in any CMS blocks or anything. Template hints won't work either

Answer (score 0):

The first place I would look is `app/design/frontend/THEME/PACKAGE/template/page` for the files `2columnns-left.phtml`, `2columns-right.phtml`, and `3columns.phtml` depending on which layout you have selected for the page you are talking to.

Since not all custom themes will update the default base files, you should also check `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page` for the same files by the same names.

I would look for `css classes` surrounding the text you want to remove and work your way up the html structure from there. You may find a reference to a separate custom/child file, or the text in plain HTML right there.

Have you already looked through your `static blocks` to ensure that nothing with the word `left` is in the identifier portion? Custom themes will often add new blocks during installation and leave them enabled so that you are aware of space there to be customized.